# Yii2 codeception command did not finished properly

Tags: yii2, codeception

Now I know this `Command Did Not Finished Properly` means that some `die` or `exit` statement occurs somewhere in the way of the test but is there is way to ignore it and see the result from that test ? I'm trying simple basic login test ( I am total newbie in tests ) and I am not sure if the test passes like an expected. It looks like so:

```
public function validLoginUser(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage('/admin/user/login');
        $I->fillField('login-form[login]', 'toma');
        $I->fillField('login-form[password]', '9110033969');
        $I->click('Log in');

        $I->see('Статистики', 'h4.text-white');
    }
```

I am pretty sure that the test pass successuly. The form is the dektrium extension Yii2 login form. Nothing changed on it. Or maybe the problem is that I am trying to test someone else's code? If it's not how can I see the result? Thank you in advance and I am sorry for the confusing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Command Did Not Finished Properly" message is printed by shutdown handler, there is no way to resume test execution from that point.

If your codebase uses `die` a lot, you could use PhpBrowser module to test over HTTP instead of using Yii2 module which executes application code in the same process.

Comment: Thank you! So with PhpBrowser module I can do functional testing not only Acceptance?